# $watch callback execution order

Tags: angularjs, callback

Here's what I have:

```
$scope.$watch('someVar', function (val) {
    $scope.someList.push(val);
    execLongFunction.then(function (data) {
        val.computedValue = data;
    })
})
```

What I want: to add a value to the array in my scope, then perform some calculations and then (maybe) update the scope. The main point is that I want `val` to be pushed to scope array before `execLongFunction` is done.

The problem is: all $watch callback code is executed, kind of, immediately: even if I add some console.log() I see all of them at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you updating `someVar` continuously.?

Comment: no, it's being updated by a directive which listens to user actions (file upload)

Comment: will the value of the someVar be changed everytime?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch('someVar', function (newVal,oldVal) {
    if(newVal != oldVal){
      $scope.someList.push(newVal);
      execLongFunction.then(function (data) {
        val.computedValue = data;
      })
    }
});
```

$watch returns both oldValue and newValue of the $scope variable you are watching. Try to use those and execute your functions accordingly. This should work if the value of 'someVar' doesn't change every time when updated from the directive.